# Delphi welcome page won't load menus

Tags: javascript, html, delphi

My problem is not about fixing an issue with a certain IDE, in this case Delphi, but is about finding out the problem that leads to the issue. You probably know that in Delphi 2010 (maybe also in some earlier versions) there's a welcome page that lists recently opened projects. It's actually an html page that also involves some js files to load menus and stuff. But recently my welcome page does not work. It does not list any menus and projects and appears like an erroneus page. I've uninstalled and reinstalled Delphi many times but the problem persists. It seems there's a problem with running some JavaScript command,which I think because of the Windows, not Delphi. Here's how the Welcome Page now looks like

[image: The Welcome Page]

Comment: Do you have the folder C:\Program Files\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\7.0\Welcomepage

Comment: Yes, I do. All the files are there. I compared them with normal working Delphis

Comment: Did you change any IE security zone settings?

Comment: I might have. What setting change can cause this?

Comment: Try clearing the internet explorer temporary files. Had a problem like this, and doing so solved the problem.

Comment: Is it possible that the javascript is blocked?

Comment: But I've got no problem with viewing any other web pages

Comment: I also restored all the settings to their defaults. But no luck

Comment: do you see something in the eventlogs of windows that cause this issue?

Comment: @Mikayil, i have a little idea, closed-source you know, but i'm under impression from studying Welcode Page's sources what it is quite vulnerable to IE's settings.

Comment: @Ravaut123, unlikely Windows' syslog, intead more sense makes an idea to invoke IE's development tools (including an error console) from within Welcome Page's browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to right click and select "browse mode" or something alike. It's a known bug, sometimes it enters "edit mode" and doesn't display correctly. IIRC there's an Hausladen [IDE fix pack](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/) that corrects it.

Comment: Design mode, not a "edit mode", as in [`javascript:window.document.designMode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla) (should be 'Off'). IDE fix pack might add its own bugs, BTW.